# How can I clean the program window when using Termdebug?

Tags: terminal-buffer, debugging

The window named *gdb program* (see `:h :Termdebug`) is the one where I can give input and view output of the program being debugged.

How can I clean it between one run and another (or when I like, in general)?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot please?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, I'm not on my computer now, but I'm referring to the window at the bottom left corner in [this gif](https://www.dannyadam.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/steps.gif). However, how would the screenshot be relevant to my question?

Comment: Okay, I am not aware of a way to force a redraw there. I guess it depends on the program you are running there. It might help to restart the program you are debugging. I wasn't sure if you not meant the gdb debugger window.

Comment: You could possibly bwipeout it?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, sorry for the late reply, but I missed the notification. `bwipeout` seems to be for wiping out something more than the _content_ of the buffer. If, from within the _gdb program_ window I hit `<Ctrl-W>:bwipeout<CR>` I get a _E89_. If I force it with `!`, the _gdb program_ window closes.